# React useState re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When i use `useState` it shows in the console 2 renders, and if i call `setVal` it throws the error `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`. Why?

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-black-j1zow?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Home() {
  console.log("render");
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState();
  // setVal(1);
  return <div></div>;
}
```

I think it should be only 1 render, and only 2 renders if i call `setVal()`, right?

Comment: You should not be calling `setVal` like that. It should either be in the "initial value" parameter to `useState`, inside of a `useEffect`, or updated via some kind of event callback.

Comment: @crashmstr Ok, but don't you know why it shows 2 renders in the console? Even if i don't update the state.

Comment: @mario Does your index.js has any wrapper like ```<React.StrictMode>``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you used *create-react-app* to startup your application, you must have `<React.StrictMode>` wrapper in your index.js file:

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>
```

The reason why this happens is an intentional feature of the React.StrictMode.

**Remove** that wrapper and it should fix it.

Comment: This is probably true, but it's working as intended and only does this in dev. Per the docs:
*Note:Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not impact the production build.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet illustrating three basic ways of setting and handling state with `useState`.

`val1` is set to 1 by providing an initial value to `useState` and doesn't change.

`val2` is not initially set, but `useEffect` is called after the initial render and sets it's value to `set with useEffect`. We have provided an empty dependency array to `useEffect` so it will only run once.

`val3` is initialized in the same way as `val1` and it's value is changed via the `handleClick` function.

As to your question about the number of renders, `useState` looks for changes of state and calls renders accordingly. By calling `setState` the way you are you are changing the state on each render and thus triggering a new render...ad infinitum. It should be noted that this is not a one to one process. The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) walk you through it pretty clearly.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="App"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState, useEffect} = React;

function Home() {
  console.log("render");
  const [val1, setVal1] = React.useState(1);
  const [val2, setVal2] = React.useState();
  const [val3, setVal3] = React.useState('Click me');
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    setVal2('set with useEffect');
  },[])
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    setVal3('set with handler');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{val1}</p>
      <p>{val2}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>{val3}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('App'));

 </script>
```